# SEO Friendly URL for PHP CMS

Tags: php, url-rewriting, content-management-system

URL Rewrite for PHP CMS

Hosting: Godaddy Windows (.htaccess does not work)

1. Want to rewrite the url www.domainname.in/category.php?ct=6 as www.domainname.in/category/sports
2. Want to rewrite the url www.domainname.in/detail-news.php?p=70 as www.domainname.in/detail-news/dummy-teams-wins-the-match

ct=6 is sports
p=70 title is dummy teams wins the match

Comment: Firstly, putting "very urgently required" won't make us reply any quicker, your time constraints are your own problem. Secondly, which CMS are you using as this will probably come with some URL rewriting functionality.

Comment: Windows IIS has the same functionality as .htaccess. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs. I am trying to make my own (CMS/Blog).

Comment: I am able to redirect the URL on localhost, but still struggling to do it on Godaddy windows hosting. My .htaccess code is 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^terms-and-conditions-of-use?$ terms-and-conditions-of-use.php
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy?$ privacy-policy.php
RewriteRule ^contact-us?$ contact-us.php
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+) category.php?ct=$1
RewriteRule ^detail-news/([0-9]+) detail-news.php?p=$1

Can anyone help me to convert this to web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the slug field in your CMS table that field will contains the name or your title 
example  : 
The is of article is 70 in your demo exp :
www.domainname.in/detail-news.php?p=70

Then the slug will be 'dummy-teams-wins-the-match' saved to that article
and when a visitor type this link, 
www.domainname.in/detail-news/dummy-teams-wins-the-match

The system's core will check if that slug exist in the database and it redirect to that article who contains the slug 'dummy-teams-wins-the-match' and id = 7

Comment: If OP made their own CMS, none of this is likely to exist.

Comment: I am trying to develop my own CMS/Blog website.